# Ruby call child method only

Tags: ruby, inheritance

I'd like to raise an exception when I call an instance method on a child but the child hasn't defined it yet. Given the code:

```
class Parent
  def foo
    'hihi'
  end
end

class Child < Parent
end
```

Is it possible to call `Child.new.foo` in a different way that would raise this exception?

I understand I can

```
class Parent
  def foo
    unless self.class.instance_methods(false).include? :foo
      raise Exception.new("Child didn't define foo!")
    end
    'hihi'
  end
end
```

I'm wondering if it's possible to do it without this and where I would actually perform the `Child.new.foo` call.

Thanks!

Comment: You could extract that check to a DSL method.

Comment: What is your use case? This seems like a lot of overhead with no direct benefit.

Comment: by the way, you should **absolutely** use `raise "Child didn't define foo!"` (it's a `RuntimeError`), never, ever raise instances of base `Exception`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do you need that plain `Parent` instances succeed in responding to `foo`?

If you are trying to make an abstract method, just raise an exception in `Parent#foo`  and avoid calling `super` in any of the subclasses' `foo`.

```
class Parent
  def foo
    raise "abstract Parent#foo"
  end
end

class Child < Parent
  # this will raise an exception
end

class OtherChild < Parent
  # this won't raise an exception
  def foo
    'blah'
  end
end
```

On the other side, you can use method inspection like this

```
class Parent
  def foo
    if self.class.instance_method(:foo).owner == Parent
      raise "abstract" unless self.instance_of? Parent
    end
    "fifi"
  end
end

class Child < Parent
  # this will raise an exception
end

class OtherChild < Parent
  # this won't raise an exception
  def foo
    'blah'
    super
  end
end
```

This has the property that any intermediate class defining the method will block the exception.

If you want to force *every* subclass to define the method (not just that there is some intermediate definition), you might use

```
if self.class.instance_method(:foo).owner != self.class
```

as the condition

Comment: He could also just remove the definition of `foo` from the parent class.

Comment: But then the call would go up in the ancestor list, and maybe some module at some point has that same method defined, or a custom `method_missing`...

Comment: @rewritten yeah Parent.new.foo still needs to be able to be called specifically Child.new.foo will call super at some point, which is why I have that particular raise exception built already.

Comment: Then your solution won't work for instance in the case of `GrandChild < Child < Parent` inheritance, when `Child` defines `foo` and `GrandChild` does not.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way to do it: implement `inherited` (see [Ruby docs](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Class.html#method-i-inherited)) in the base class, and from there define the method you want to force the child class to override:

```
class Parent
  def self.inherited(child)
    child.send(:define_method, :foo) do
      raise "You must implement #{child}#foo!"
    end
  end

  def foo
    'hihi'
  end
end
```

Now any class inheriting from `Parent` will start off with a `foo` method that throws an exception. When you implement `foo` explicitly in the derived class, it will override this default implementation.

What I like about this approach is that it shouldn't add extra overhead to every call to `foo`.

Comment: @rewritten: Yeah, just noticed that in a comment. I may think up a way to make that work, or just delete this answer momentarily.

Comment: See my answer, you can check the value of `self.class.instance_method(:foo).owner`, which is the actual class that defined the called method.

Comment: @rewritten: I think my updated answer has an even better approach. Let me know if there's an obvious downside I'm missing.

Comment: If a grandchild defines the method and calls super, then the child would raise the RuntimeError. I don't think it's the expected behavior.